# NoClassDefFoundError в maven зависимости

Tags: java, maven

Вопрос, конечно, заезженный, однако ни одно из найденных решений, мне не помогло.

Пишу приложение на `spring mvc`. При запуске на томкате из ide всё хорошо.

Мавеном собираю `war`-файл, разворачиваю на отдельно запущенном томкате. Весь основной функционал работает, но при попытке загрузить файл на сервер, в ответ получаю `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream`.

Зависимость в `pom` указана. Сама библиотека с требуемым файлом в варнике есть. 
Все библиотеки, кроме этой, видит. Если проблема в `classpath`, то почему все остальные библиотеки при этом нормально подтягиваются?

8 томакат со стандартными либами. Запускаю без каких-либо параметров, обычным startup.bat.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ru.sidorov</groupId>
<artifactId>findparty</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>findparty</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-vkontakte</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet Spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1203-jdbc42</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-request-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-request-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-request-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-autotag-core-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-milestones</id>
        <name>SpringSource Milestones Proxy</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-milestones</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Контроллер 
    package ru.sidorov.controller;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import ru.sidorov.model.Entity.UserEntity;
import ru.sidorov.model.UserData;
import ru.sidorov.service.UserService;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("userData")
public class FileUploadController  {

@Value("${avatars.path}")
private String avatarsPath;
@Value("${defaultAvatar}")
private String defaultAvatar;

@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String provideUploadInfo() {
    return "Вы можете загружать файл с использованием того же URL.";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request){
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        if(!file.getContentType().contains("image")) {
            return "неверный формат";
        }
        try {
            String originalFilename = file.getOriginalFilename();
            String format = originalFilename.substring(originalFilename.lastIndexOf("."));

            String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis()  + format;
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            BufferedOutputStream stream =
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(/*avatarsPath + */fileName)));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();

            UserData userData = (UserData) request.getSession().getAttribute("userData");

            UserService userService = new UserService();
            UserEntity user = userService.findById(userData.getId());

            if(user.getAvatar() !=null){
                File oldFile = new File("avatarsPath"+user.getAvatar() );
                oldFile.delete();
            }
            user.setAvatar(fileName);
            userService.update(user);

            return "ok";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Вам не удалось загрузить  => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "Вам не удалось загрузить  потому что файл пустой.";
    }
  }
}
```

Стектрейс

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:191)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:350)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:158)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:142)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:928)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:191)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:350)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:158)
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:142)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:928)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-io**

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ findparty ---
[INFO] ru.sidorov:findparty:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4)
[INFO] \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
```

**mvn dependency:list-repositories**

```
[INFO] Repositories Used by this build:
 [INFO]       id: jboss-public-repository
  url: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
 layout: default
 snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]

 [INFO]       id: central
  url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
  layout: default
  snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
  releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]

 [INFO]       id: my-alternate-repository
  url: http://www.mvnrepository.com
  layout: default
  snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
  releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]

 [INFO]       id: jboss
  url: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases
  layout: default
  snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
  releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]

 [INFO]       id: springsource-milestones
  url: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-milestones
  layout: default
  snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
  releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]

 [INFO]       id: maven central
  url: http://repo1.maven.org/maven/
  layout: default
  snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
  releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
```

**Решение**

Разобраться, почему приложение не видит библиотеку, которая лежит в варнике, я так и не смог. Решил просто положив `commons-fileupload` и `commons-io` в библиотеки томката. На jboss поднялось вообще без каких либо манипуляций и без зависимостей `commons-fileupload` и `commons-io` в `pom`'e

Answer (score 5):

Spring использует [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/download_fileupload.cgi) для загрузки файлов. Это [опциональная](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) [звисимость](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/build.gradle), поэтому проблему вы получаете только в рантайме. Добавьте в проект:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

`commons-io` подтянется сам, но можно объявить отдельно

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

---

**Обновление**

Проверьте, что у вас настроен `MultipartResolver`.

Пример для аннотаций

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
            @Bean
            public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
                CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
                multipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
                return multipartResolver;
            }
}
```

Пример для XML

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
     class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
</bean>
```

Обновите `servlet-api` хотя бы до 3.0

---

```
sandbox/test » mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-io

[INFO] test:test:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4)
[INFO] \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
```

Comment: `commons-fileupload` подключен

Comment: @Sapphiron  Ну тогда уж делитесь полной информацией. Выкладывайте ваш `pom.xml`, код контроллера вместе с импортами. Что у вас за томкат, с какими ключами он запущен, что у него в `./lib` лежит...

Comment: добавил пом, контроллер и стектрейс

Comment: @Sapphiron обновил

Comment: `MultipartResolver` настроен.    `<bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="200000"/>
    </bean>`. Обновил `servlet-api` до 3.1.0, но не помогло. Эх, магия.

Comment: @Sapphiron сконфигурировано все правильно. На пробу запустил ваш `pom.xml` с [простым приложением](https://github.com/krams915/spring-fileupload-tutorial) на tomcat 8 - все работает. Видимо действительно проблема в classpath, если вы уверены, что `commons-*` точно есть в `WEB-INF/lib`. Дальше я бы попробовал вывести в дебаг список файлов в classpath приложения, проверить classpath JRE, запустить простое приложение, ссылка на которое дана выше.

Comment: Кстати, если используете `maven-war-plugin`, то может там какой-то параметр заигрался.

Comment: Приложение из туториала работает нормально, файлы загружаются. Достал все ресурсы из `classpath` с помощью `Resource[] resources = p.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX);` и обе библиотеки присутствуют `commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar!
commons-io-2.4.jar!`

Comment: Ах да. И при сборке `maven-war-plugin` появляются проблемы с конфигом хибернейта, поэтому, я собираю просто `mvn package`.

Comment: @Sapphiron Попробуйте собрать `mvn clean install`. Добавьте в вопрос вывод  команды. `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-io`

Comment: Добавил вывод `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-io`

Comment: @Sapphiron Такого быть не должно. Надо найти на какой библиотеке ломается билд `mvn dependency:tree --debug`. Кстати, когда я собирал ваш `pom.xml`, там действительно не было указанных версий `org.springframework.social` в maven central - не знаю откуда вы их тянете, и у `spring-social-vkontakte` [неправильный groupId](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.weekens%7Cspring-social-vkontakte%7C1.1.0.RELEASE%7Cjar). Также можно удалить локальный репозиторий maven (~/.m2), сохранив, естественно, настройки, или попробовать собрать на другой машине.

Comment: Удалил папку локального репозитория, вернул стандартный `settings.xml` без данных рабочего репозитория, поправил зависимости и выкачал всё еще раз. Ошибка сохранилась, но вывод `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-io` теперь нормальный, обновил в сообщении.

Comment: @Sapphiron Из этого можно сделать заключение, что maven не видит зависимость `commons-fileupload`, иначе она обязательно была вы в выводе команды, поскольку тянет за собой `commons-io`. Также в вашем `pom.xml` вы вы подключаете `2.4`, а выводе у вас только `2.2`. Как так.. Добавил в ответ нормальный вывод команды.

Comment: @Sapphiron Покажите, пожалуйста, вывод `mvn dependency:list-repositories`

Comment: Обновил `commons-fileupload` и `commons-io` до последних версий, вывод стал как у Вас. Обновил. Добавил вывод `mvn dependency:list-repositories`.

Comment: Попробовал перенести весь код в `spring-fileupload-tutorial`, просто добавив недостающие зависимости. Появилась та же ошибка..Видимо, проблема в подключаемых библиотеках.

Comment: @Sapphiron А можете скинуть получившийся туториал с ошибкой куда-нибудь? Просто даже уже интересно стало, что там за ерунда такая.

Comment: с туториалом уже кучу всего накрутил) вот ссылка на сам мой проект https://bitbucket.org/Sapphiron/findparty2

Comment: @Sapphiron С виду все что нужно есть. Подключите логгер, посмотрите дебаг спринга; сделайте Class.forName(..) для проблемного класса; подключите какой-нибудь [classpath-inspector](https://habrahabr.ru/post/268393/) Если не поможет - ищите рабочую точку - поэтапно убирайте не относящиеся к проблеме зависимости и код и смотрите когда проблема исчезнет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35786/discussion-on-answer-by-enzo-noclassdeffounderror--maven-).